# Remove multiple objects from arraylist in android

Tags: android, arraylist

I have an `ArrayList<String>` A that contains n elements, and an `ArrayList<Integer>` B that contains the indexes from A that I need to delete. How can I delete these indexes? After I remove an index like this : `A.remove(index)`, then the size of A is smaller and the others indexes are not on the same position anymore.

Any idea is welcome.

Comment: you may want to consider another data structure as this doesn't seem like a great solution (I don't know what you're trying to do). Maybe talk about what you want to do and I think we could have a fun discussion of how best to implement it :P

Comment: Why are you not using a HashMap or SparseArray rather than two different ArrayLists? It sounds like the two items are correlated with each other, keep them in a HashMap or SparseArray and then they are directly linked and can be removed in one call.

Comment: I agree with HashMap but I will add that you will want to check out LinkedHashMap if you want the items to keep the same order.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to sort them (Collections.sort() probably works out of the box for integer arraylist), and start by removing the bigger index first.

Answer (score 3):

If you don't have duplicate Strings in your list you can create a list with the objects you want to remove and then call the removeAll(Collection c) method for your array list.

if `stringList` is the list with your Strings and `indexList` is the list of your index:

```
List<String> toRemove = new ArrayList<String>();

for(Integer i : indexList){
 toRemove.add(stringList.get(i));
}
stringList.removeAll(toRemove);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    for(int i = 0; i < arrayListInt.size(); i++){
    int arrayIndexInIntArray = arrayListInt.get(i);
    int arrayIndexToRemove = 0;
        for (Iterator iterator = arrrayList.getIterator(); iterator.hasNext();) {

                                    String tempString = (String) iterator.next();
                                    if (arrayIndexInIntArray == arrayIndexToRemove) { //Some condition
                                        iterator.remove();//Remove the value at the current iterator
break;
                                    }
arrayIndexToRemove ++;
    }
                                }
    }
```

Try this.

Answer (score 0):

The behaviour you're looking for is best achieved using a different data structure. I myself thought of a [HashMap](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/HashMap.html) (see also: [Map](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Map.html)).